# Unable to override automatic model find method calls since upgrading to Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple trait which I use to always include soft-deleted items for a few things:

```
trait OverrideTrashedTrait {

    public static function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        return parent::withTrashed()->find($id, $columns);
    }

}
```

However, since upgrading to Laravel 5.1, this no longer works. Soft-deleted items do not turn up in `get()` lists, and if I try to access a page where I've used route model bindings, I get the `NotFoundHttpException`.

Laravel's upgrade documentation states that:

> If you are overriding the `find` method in your own models and calling `parent::find()` within your custom method, you should now change it to call the  `find` method on the Eloquent query builder:

So I changed the trait accordingly:

```
trait OverrideTrashedTrait {

    public static function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        return static::query()->withTrashed()->find($id, $columns);
    }

}
```

But it appears that no matter what I write in there, it doesn't affect the results. I have also tried to put the overriding `find()` method directly in the model, but that doesn't appear to be working either. The only way anything changes is if I write invalid syntax. Even if I change the `$id` to a hardcoded id of an item that is not soft-deleted, I get the same result, and absolutely nothing happens if I e.g. try to `dd('sdfg')`, so I doubt the method is even called.

Edit: If I do trigger the method manually, it works just like intended.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show the code where you call find please.

Comment: If I do trigger it manually, the function works as intended - thanks, I'll add that to the question. But I mostly don't call it manually. The route model binding does so automatically. In the case of e.g. get calls, any kind of call would trigger it in Laravel 5.0, such as `App\SomeModel::get();`, but apparently doesn't in 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here it goes:

**short version**: Model binding does not use find.

**longer version**:

```
/**
 * Register a model binder for a wildcard.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  string  $class
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function model($key, $class, Closure $callback = null)
{
    $this->bind($key, function ($value) use ($class, $callback) {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return;
        }

        // For model binders, we will attempt to retrieve the models using the first
        // method on the model instance. If we cannot retrieve the models we'll
        // throw a not found exception otherwise we will return the instance.
        $instance = new $class;

        if ($model = $instance->where($instance->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first()) {
            return $model;
        }

        // If a callback was supplied to the method we will call that to determine
        // what we should do when the model is not found. This just gives these
        // developer a little greater flexibility to decide what will happen.
        if ($callback instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func($callback, $value);
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    });
}
```

Line 931 of Illuminate\Routing\Router says it does:

```
$instance->where($instance->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first()
```

It uses the key from the model used in a where and loads the first result.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know where to look. I compared with the 5.0 source and apparently it was changed - it did use `find()` previously. That only leaves the question of how to solve it...

Comment: In your model you can overrule the where method. Or you can stop using route models and use the Id in your controller.. Or you can overrule the whole Router object for your application and implement a different model method.. so many choices.

Comment: Yes, I can think of several. Ideally I would like to use a clean, generalisable method, though. Will have to give it some thought.

Comment: I would open an issue on the framework. Ask Taylor about this decision and a solution.

Comment: Probably a good idea. Thanks. I'll mark your answer as correct, don't think we'll get any closer here. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.1 `find()` method can be found in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

From your Model class you can override it like following:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Overrides find() method in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.
     * Finds only active products.
     * 
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|null
     */
    public static function find($id, $columns = ['*']) {
        // create builder from the Model
        $builder = (new self)->newQuery();

        // method customization
        if (is_array($id)) {
            // findMany() also should be customized
            return self::findMany($id, $columns);
        }

        $builder->getQuery()->where("isActive", '=', 1)->where($builder->getModel()->getQualifiedKeyName(), '=', $id);

        return $builder->first($columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting - I appreciate your time. However, the question is almost two years old, and I don't think you understood it.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that, but I think it is good solution (I did not find another one on http://stackoverflow.com), so I posted it to make a bookmark at least for myself... :) Maybe one day it will be interesting for someone else... :) Solution is still actual for L5.4